# Why does my R notebook produce a blank html document

Tags: knitr, rnotebook

For some reason, my R notebook is producing a blank HTML document. When I'm ready to knit the document to an html notebook, my browser opens up the file and it is a blank document.  I'm pressing the "knit" button, then "html" from R Studio.

Here is my code:

````
---
title: "Rate Hole Model"
output: html_document
---
```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(rmarkdown)
library(knitr)
```


```{r}
 veh_age <- mc2 %>%
    filter(cummulative < 51)

plot_ly(veh_age, x = ~unit_age, y = ~loss_ratio, color = ~rating_class_name) %>%
  add_markers(text = ~paste(rating_class_name,  "<br />", 'unit age: ', 
              unit_age, "<br />", 'loss ratio: ', loss_ratio), hoverinfo = 
             'text') %>%
  layout(title = 'Comp Loss Ratio by Unit Age/Rating Class')
```
````

I'm not sure what happened.  I'm on R version 3.5.1Has anyone ran into this problem?

Answer (score 1):

My Libraries were installed to my Home directory : *\Home\firstname.lastname\documents*.  This directory is a network located resource.  When the last step of the process ran, the proper permission was not available to the called application (Pandoc).  I am running *64 bit* *Win 10* with *64 bit* RStudio *version 1.1.456* and the *3.5 version* of R. When I moved (reinstalled) the packages/libraries to a local folder : *c:\Program Files\RStudio\Packages* the HTML rendered in the browser.

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. This post is better suited as a comment).